# criteria query mongodb - spring boot - regex- pattern: start with

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, criteria-api, criteriaquery

I have one string variable **value="System.Ram.*"** ,which will use to fetch any property start with System.Ram (e.g. System.Ram.dell,System.Ram.intel etc.)

I want to use something like this:

```
Criteria.where(property).regex(pattern_of_value)
```

Can anyone please help me this ? Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

`Criteria.where(property).regex("^System.Ram");`

Or use below (here `value` is "System.Ram"):

`Criteria.where(property).regex("^" + value);`